# Non-ableist alternative to "blind spot"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

The phrase "blind spot" has been called ableist. For someone looking to avoid it, what are some good alternatives?

Sample sentences:

- We need to be aware of our **blind spots** to make sure a competitor doesn't surprise us in the market.
- Employee morale has been a **blind spot** for us in the past, but Sarah is doing a great job of tracking it now.
- Quentin has good ideas when it comes to pricing strategy, but she has a **blind spot** when it comes to the best way to present a proposal.

Comment: (There's a past question in https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325850/synonym-for-blind-spot but it seems rather a different request, despite the similar title.)

Comment: `The phrase "blind spot" has been called ableist` – by whom? Is this a prevailing view within the disability community and deserving of consideration, or an extreme view by a tiny minority and should be dismissed? Please support your statement with suitable evidence so that we can better judge how to respond. :-)

Comment: PS in all three examples, an obvious candidate to avoid the anatomical reference would be "weakness" (or its plural). Synonyms such as "vulnerability" or "difficulty" would also fit. I'm posting this as a comment rather than writing an answer, because basic research (consulting a thesaurus) would readily supply my suggested solution.

Comment: “Officer the other car was in my willful ignorance.”

Comment: Is 'oversight' superheroist?

Answer (score 9):

A *Blind Spot* is **not** a term about blind people but the anatomy of the human eye. The optic nerve that brings information from the retina to the brain is off-center of the eye, not directly opposite the lens. Where this bundling occurs the light sensing capabilities of the eye are very weak. With binocular vision the weakness in each eye is compensated. Even with one eye it is so slight that one can barely notice. It takes closing one eye and staring with the other at a particular target to notice the weak spot off to the side in the peripheral vision.

And for what its worth blind people happily use "See you later" and related expressions with no fuss or aggrieved embarrassment. Those hoping to find forgiveness by correcting their "ableist" thinking can never wash the sin from their hands this way. I was told this by my piano teacher, yes blind, among others.

To answer Sophie's considerate comment I will add that it is not *etymology* but accurate *anatomy* that is the solution to the question. *Blind Spot* is a perfectly accurate and acceptable use of a human anatomical shortcoming. One of many we have and of which we must humbly admit when describing complex interactions where we may fail to see all the incoming information. I am happy if sorry to admit my limitations. Blind Spot needs no apologist nor apology. Thank you.

I would normally agree strongly with *Chappo Hasn't Forgotten Monica* and thanks for the comment. But no apologies this time. This is not the question of which term might be better. The premise is mistaken and pernicious. That is to control speech or what we use here, writing, in order to solve a fictive problem. Things move rapidly from preferred speech codes to required speech codes and they do so starting right here.

Comment: I'm quite aware of the etymology. What you've written is informative but decidedly not an answer to the question – perhaps you'd like to add it as a comment instead?

Comment: +1 Challenging the premise of a question has long been an accepted way to answer questions. Here, exposing the faulty premise has been done very well.

Comment: *Blind Spot* doesn't refer only to the anatomical phenomenon you describe, in my experience it is also commonly used in situations where some external object is partially obstructing a (typically small, but sometimes crucial) part of one's view, such as the blind spots car drivers need to allow for.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very well written article about why ableist language is harmful: https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20210330-the-harmful-ableist-language-you-unknowingly-use

And a great resource for alternatives to common everyday ableist phrases: https://www.autistichoya.com/p/ableist-words-and-terms-to-avoid.html

From that resource, some good alternatives could be:

- an area of weakness
- lack of knowledge
- willfully ignorant
- deliberately ignoring
- turning their back on
- overcome by prejudice
- doubly anonymous (specifically for double-blind studies)
- had every reason to know
- feigned ignorance

Your sample phrases could become:

- We need to be aware of our **understanding gaps** to make sure a competitor
  doesn't surprise us in the market.
- Employee morale has been an **area of weakness** for us in the past,
  but Sarah is doing a great job of tracking it now.
- Quentin has good ideas when it comes to pricing strategy, but she **lacks expertise** when it comes to the best way to present a proposal.

In all of the cases above, using different phrases has led to a more accurate description of what has caused the area of weakness: a lack of information vs skills gap and so the phrases are in fact more accurate and powerful than with the harmful ableist phrase "blind-spot".

All that being said, language is complex and continually evolving and it will, personally, take me many years to adapt my own phraseology and that is all the more reason to start now and become increasingly conscious of the marginalizing effect our language can have through our own subconscious biases.

Comment: *"Employee morale has been an area of weakness for us in the past,"* - This losies the original implication that *blind spot* conveyed that the company was not previously aware they had a problem with morale.

Answer (score 1):

I am fascinated by this conversation. As my friend Lisa says, these phrases, beyond being ableist, are just lazy use of language and we could be much clearer in our meanings.

Stating that "Employee morale has been a **blind spot** for us..." gives the impression that it just "is",
whereas "Employee morale has been an **area of weakness**..." leaves the impression that something will be done about it. This alternative, "area of weakness", is not ableist and its meaning is more clear.

That being said, the poster above is right that the term "blind" has multiple meanings however that doesn't mean one shouldn't be more thoughtful about how it is used.

Answer (score -2):

I would not necessarily agree that it's ableist language, but I think "dead angle" is pretty much a drop-in synonym you could use instead, if you wish.  [Wiktionary offers this definition of the term](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dead_angle):

> An angle or space which cannot be seen or defended from behind the parapet of a fortification.

This usage is definitely less common but is attested in other places; for instance, [this article makes reference to a "dead angle mirror"](https://bikeportland.org/2008/05/13/black-spot-mirrors-save-lives-in-amsterdam-7542) where we might otherwise see "blind spot mirror."

Comment: A disadvantage is that readers won't understand it. By contrast, the figurative use of "blind spot" is well known.

Comment: @RosieF Yes, "blind spot" is the most familiar term, but if you wish to avoid it you will have to use a less common one.  If I search for the phrase I do turn up results for, for instance, "dead angle mirrors" for sale.

Comment: That said, you could say that about any term that someone wishes to avoid.  If enough people see it your way eventually the alternatives won't sound weird anymore.